# Button reacts to the screen event in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I use Unity 2019.4. I made a script so that if a make a long press on the screen of my mobile phone, my Personnal Character stops. I created a button to shoot gun too. The problem is when I make long press on that button too (shoot button), my personal character also stops. How to avoid this and use "Shoot button" only for shooting.

```
        if (MobileInput.Instance.LongPress) 
        {
            {
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, 0, 1f);
                if (speed <= 0)
                {
                    speed = 0;
                    isIdle = true;
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is adding a bool to check if you are currently firing an option for you and just check on the long press if you are not firing? `if (MobileInput.Instance.LongPress && !isFiring)`

Comment: Did you check out past Q&A on similar topics, like [UI clicks hitting game objects velow](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134504/39518),, [How to block interaction below panel](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/118020/39518), etc? A common solution recommended in these cases is using `EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject` to check if the touch is on a button and disregard it.

Comment: I will. Thanks!

Comment: If an answer works, remember to come back and hit the check mark, so others know it worked for you.

Comment: What I was looking for is what DMGregory suggested. It is how to BLOCK interaction below panel. I did not express it correctly in the begining.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it thanks to suggestions I received. 
 In my Input script(where Mobile and Keyboard Inputs are handled),I inserted "EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject()". I removed Image component in the UI Panel coz Image component can be transparent so invisible but it can block interaction with the screen (taps and swipes on the screen).

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            return;
            
        tap = true;
        startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zibelas said in the comments, you could use an `isShooting` bool to check whether or not you are firing, and thus prevent the player from stopping when the input happens to be a longpress. Here's the script:

```
public bool isShooting;

        if (MobileInput.Instance.LongPress && !isShooting) 
        {
            {
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, 0, 1f);
                if (speed <= 0)
                {
                    speed = 0;
                    isIdle = true;
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }
```